# Chdir lagging Shell

Tags: c++, shell

I am writing a shell in C/C++. When I try changing the directory with `chdir(const char*)`, the shell starts to lag. The shell works very good until somthing like `cd ..` is typed. Then when I try typing `ls`, it says it cannot execute `couldn't execute: l` (not `ls`).
to build: `g++ main.cc -lreadline`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <readline/readline.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>

#define clear printf("\033[H\033[J")

char** getInput(char* input)
{
  char** command = (char**) malloc(8 * sizeof(char*));
  char* separator = " ";
  char* parsed;
  int index = 0;

  parsed = strtok(input, separator);
  while (parsed != NULL)
    {
      command[index] = parsed;
      index++;

      parsed = strtok(NULL, separator);
    }

  command[index] = NULL;
  return command;
}

int main()
{
  char** command;
  char* input;
  pid_t child_pid;
  int stat_loc;

  bool loop = true;
  do
    {
      input = readline("");
      command = getInput(input);
      child_pid = fork();
      if (child_pid < 0)
        {
          printf("Fork Failed\n");
          exit(0);
        }
      if (strncmp(command[0], "cd\n", 2) == 0)
        {
          if (chdir(std::string(command[1]).c_str()) < 0)
            printf("Couldn't execute: %s\n", command[1]);
          continue;
        }
      else if (child_pid == 0)
        {
          execvp(command[0], command);
          printf("couldn't execute: %s\n", input);
        }
      else waitpid(child_pid, &stat_loc, WUNTRACED);
      free(input);
      free(command);
    } while (loop);
}
```

Comment: This is `c`, not `c++`

Comment: `std::string(command[1]).c_str()` : double conversion from a C string to a C++ `std::string` and then immediately back to a C string ? What for?

Comment: You are right. I do not need that line. Thanks for spotting it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are forking at the wrong position, resulting in spawning multiple children when using command `cd`. In addition to that, the `continue` for command `cd` prevents freeing `input` and `command`. Also, the child needs to break the loop to exit after running the command.

So this:

```
      child_pid = fork();
      if (child_pid < 0)
        {
          printf("Fork Failed\n");
          exit(0);
        }
      if (strncmp(command[0], "cd\n", 2) == 0)
        {
          if (chdir(std::string(command[1]).c_str()) < 0)
            printf("Couldn't execute: %s\n", command[1]);
          continue;
        }
      else if (child_pid == 0)
        {
          execvp(command[0], command);
          printf("couldn't execute: %s\n", input);
        }
      else waitpid(child_pid, &stat_loc, WUNTRACED);
```

should be:

```
      if (strncmp(command[0], "cd\n", 2) == 0)
        {
          if (chdir(std::string(command[1]).c_str()) < 0)
            printf("Couldn't execute: %s\n", command[1]);
          free(input);
          free(command);
          continue;
        }
      child_pid = fork();
      if (child_pid < 0)
        {
          printf("Fork Failed\n");
          exit(0);
        }
      else if (child_pid == 0)
        {
          execvp(command[0], command);
          printf("couldn't execute: %s\n", input);
          loop = false;
          // or:
          //free(input);
          //free(command);
          //exit(0);
        }
      else waitpid(child_pid, &stat_loc, WUNTRACED);
```